# Underscores Theme Unit Testing - Catching Untitled Posts

Tags: posts, theme-development, unit-tests

Wordpress 5.0.3 | Underscores Theme

I'm unit testing a theme I based on underscores using the wptest.io xml.

Underscores does not gracefully catch untitled posts. There is no title in either singular or list form if the post title is blank.

In the theme's content.php, this is what exists:

```
if ( is_singular() ) :
    the_title( '<h1 class="entry-title">', '</h1>' );
else :
    the_title( '<h2 class="entry-title"><a href="' . esc_url( get_permalink() ) . '" rel="bookmark">', '</a></h2>' );
endif;
```

This is the solution I came up with:

```
$low_title_cleaned = esc_attr( $post->post_title );  // Is there a title?
$low_untitled = __( 'Untitled Document', 'laughter_on_water' ); // Internationalize...
if ( is_singular() && $low_title_cleaned ) { // Title h1
    the_title( '<h1 class="entry-title">', '</h1> title: ' );
} elseif ( !is_singular() && $low_title_cleaned ) { // Title h2
    the_title( '<h2 class="entry-title"><a href="' . esc_url( get_permalink() ) . '" rel="bookmark">', '</a></h2>' );
} elseif ( is_singular() && !$low_title_cleaned ) { // Untilled h1
    echo '<h1 class="entry-title">' . $low_untitled . '</h1>';
} elseif ( !is_singular() && !$low_title_cleaned ) { // Untilled h1
    echo '<h2 class="entry-title"><a href="' . esc_url( get_permalink() ) . '" rel="bookmark">' . $low_untitled . '</a></h2>';
}
```

Questions:
Is this code reasonably secure?

Is there a shorter, more elegant way to manage the same?

Does it make sense to contribute something like this to core, wp-includes/post-template.php? It just returns nothing on line 46.

Comment: great questions. Why not submit and see what Holger (the developer) says...

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I've looked on both the underscores and wordpress sites for information on Holger. I am having little luck. Can you give me a link?

Comment: Chris, sorry.  Holger is the developer of underSTRAP. (underscores + bootstrap).  Your question could be asked here though: https://github.com/automattic/_s/issues